# iPhone : mkv/mka parsing libraries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkv, matroska

This may sound a newbie question however I'm new to iOS dev.

Are there any mkv parser libraries for iOS, please suggest some links.
Also I would like to know if their license do not conflict with Apple's applications store terms ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to answer to my own question, the result of my research are. Following projects can be used to achieve mentioned functionality libVLC, libVLCcore and libVLC more info here http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ios.html

Comment: Be aware that VLC is under GPL licence! Same goes to FFmpeg, which you could use as well, but is also under GPL.