# How to switch audio track in .mkv file on Chromecast (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I found that we can add `mediaTracks` for external `audio` and `subtitles`. And activate it with `setActiveTrackIDs`.

But how I can change current audio track from english to different language? Any code example? Infuse player in store somehow can do this.

**Edit**

One idea is to change default audio track in media file and reload from Chromecast. Dig little inside `ffmpeg`, understand this not easy if you not have experience.

The other idea is to retrieve audio stream data from video, and provide it with custom media server. This is also not trivial.

Third idea is [AirConnect](https://github.com/philippe44/AirConnect), but it works only with audio. Dig into VLC player code, found that there something similar implemented on low level programming.

Comment: Set the tracks with:  https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/RemoteMediaClient#setActiveMediaTracks(long[])
Get the active tracks with: 
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/MediaStatus.html#getActiveTrackIds()

Comment: @AnjaneeshRayapati and how I can set other language for audio track in `mkv` file. Audio track contains in video. I want to switch between

Comment: You'll need parsing of your mkv file in order to extract its tracks, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785474/iphone-mkv-mka-parsing-libraries

Comment: For Audio tracks : https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/tracks#audio-tracks

Answer (score 0):

The Chromecast doesn't support audio tracks on MKV. You would have to switch them on the sender's end.

Comment: Any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: I found `MKVProperEdit` for `Matroska` files only. But it's dirty hack. How other players in AppStore (ex. nPlayer) change audio on the fly?

Comment: I'm guessing apps that do it use the ffmpeg libraries.